# Implementing Enhanced Ecommerce for Woocommerce (Without Plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics, woocommerce, enhanced-ecommerce

I'm trying to implement Enhanced Ecommerce for an e-commerce site managed by WooCommerce (currently using **Version 2.4.11**, without the possibility of an update), without using the WooCommerce Enhanced Ecommerce Plugin.

How do I do that? So far, I've got this:

```
<script>

(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-68273318-1', 'auto');
ga('require','ec');
ga('ec:addProduct', {                 // Provide product details in an productFieldObject.
  'id': '<?php the_ID(); ?>',                     // Product ID (string).
  'name': '<?php do_action( 'htb_woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );?>',  // Product name (string).
});
ga('ec:setAction', 'detail');       // Detail action.
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

It's outputting the correct ID and name, but is that all I need to do? How do I get `productImpressions` and clicks in product lists?